# stopPropagation() not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I'm new to Javascript and I'm trying my best to develop intuition for how events work in jquery. I'm developing a interactive user interface that allows users to edit objects attached to a component cell. In my code, I've created a grid of 2 columns and many rows. One of the columns consist of cells with the following html structure:

When the user hovers over that cell, 3 buttons pop up: new, edit, delete.

This all works but I'm having issues with:
1. When the button is clicked, the menu doesn't appear. Also I believe there is event propagation to the ancestor component even though I use stopPropagation in button.click(). As a result clicking on the button invokes component.click() thus generating a new set of buttons.

```
$(function() {

    var $table = $('table');
    var $form = $('<form>')
    for (i = 42; i > 0; i--) {
        $table.append('<tr><td class = "number">' + i + 
            '</td><td class = "component"></td></tr>');
    }
    /*
    $('td.component').on('click', function(e) {
        $(this).append('<button type = "submit" class = "new"><img class = "icon" src = "images/new.png" >new</img></button>' +
            '<button class = "edit"><img class = "icon" src = "images/edit.png">edit</img></button>' +
            '<button class = "delete"><img class = "icon" src = "images/delete.png">delete</img></button>');
    });*/
    /* support for hovering*/
    $('td.component').mouseover(function() {
        //$(this).css('background-color', '#ADD8E6');   
        $(this).append('<button class = "new"><img class = "icon" src = "images/new.png" >new</img></button>' +
            '<button class = "edit"><img class = "icon" src = "images/edit.png">edit</img></button>' +
            '<button class = "delete"><img class = "icon" src = "images/delete.png">delete</img></button>');
        });
    $('td.component').mouseout(function() {
        $(this).css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
        $('button').remove();
    });

    $('button').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).show();
    });

    $('button.new').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        componentMenu();
    });
    $('button.edit').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $('button.delete').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    function componentMenu() {
        var $menu = $('<select>');
        $menu.append('<option>Bloodhound</option>');
        $menu.append('<option>Compute</option>');
        $menu.append('<option>Powershelf</option>');
        $menu.append('<option>Storage</option>');
        $menu.append('<option>Switch</option>');
    }

});
```

1. Also when the user hovers over the component and then moves the cursor over the buttons the buttons fades in and out sporadically. I'm not sure how to prevent this effect though...one thought I had was to code mouseover for the button like this:

   $('button').mouseover(function() {
       $(this).show();
   });

but this didn't make any difference.

I appreciate the help.

Comment: `stopPropagation` is a method of an event object.

Comment: Have you tried `$('button.new').click(function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); });`?

Comment: Didn't realize that it was a method of an event object. I made that fix but still didn't stop the click from invoking the $('component').click().

Comment: You realise your `componentMenu()` function doesn't *do* anything, right? Also, you're probably binding event handlers to your buttons **before** they exist.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what your overall goal is, but let me go through the problems and show you possible solutions.

### Showing menu on click

From your code I assume that you want to show menu anytime user click the *new* button. There are two problems there (as @Phil already noted):

#### 1. Button click event handlers are bound before the buttons exist

Since you create the buttons in your hovering functions, the click handlers are bound to nothing. To solve this you can either use `jQuery.live` or bound the handlers to the whole table. I prefer the latter solution for its elegance:

```
$table.on('click', 'button.new', function(e) {
    // button new clicked
});
$table.on('click', 'button.edit', function(e) {
    // button edit clicked
});
$table.on('click', 'button.delete', function(e) {
    // button delete clicked
});
```

#### 2. `componentMenu` function does not really do anything

The code of `componentMenu` just creates the jQuery representation of the menu element, but it is not appended to the DOM anywhere. Simplest solution is to just append it anywhere you want it to appear.

```
function componentMenu() {
    var $menu = $('<select>');
    $menu.append('<option>Bloodhound</option>');
    $menu.append('<option>Compute</option>');
    $menu.append('<option>Powershelf</option>');
    $menu.append('<option>Storage</option>');
    $menu.append('<option>Switch</option>');

    $menu.appendTo('element-to-append-menu-to');
}
```

### Buttons fading in and out

The sporadical fading in and out of buttons is caused by use of `mouseover`/`mouseout` events. Event `mouseover` is triggered anytime user moves the mouse over the element, which causes the buttons to redraw anytime the mouse moves.

Possible solution is to use `mouseenter` event, which is triggered only once when user's mouse starts hovering over the element, and `mouseleave` event, which is triggered also just once when user's mouse ends hovering over the element.

```
$('td.component').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).append('<button class = "new"><img class = "icon" src = "images/new.png" >new</img></button>' +
        '<button class = "edit"><img class = "icon" src = "images/edit.png">edit</img></button>' +
        '<button class = "delete"><img class = "icon" src = "images/delete.png">delete</img></button>');
    });
$('td.component').mouseleave(function() {
    $('button').remove();
});
```

### Working example

I have put your [code into jsbin](http://jsbin.com/riduxibo/2/edit) and updated it with all the solutions as well as improved it a bit.

Hope it helps.